# MySql: Mapping Table or All data in same table?

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures

I am working on a project which uses a table for storing all restaurant data in same table. 
There is a separate table for area containing `area_id` and `area_name`

There are six field which are source of problem to me.
They are:

```
delivery_area_1 , delivery_area_2, delivery_area_3
minimum_order_1, minimum_order_2 and minimum_order_3
```

`delivery_area_1` field contain a coma(',') separated list of all `area_id` 's in which the restaurant delivers at minimum order 1 and so on for delivery area 2 and 3.

When a user search by `area_id` and the result contains all the restaurants which deliver in that area_id and the corresponding minimum order is to be displayed in the result along with other details.

I propose to move this delivery area data to a separate mapping table which will contain:

`restaurant_id, area_id and the minimum order`.

But doing so will cause the number of entries in the mapping table to crosss 1000,000 for 20,000 restaurants. Currently there are 1000 restaurants but the number will increase rapidly from now on. Each restaurant delivers in about 30-80 areas.

Is this a good move? It would be a big decision. So please help me with the approach.

Is there a better way to simplify and optimize search ?

Its a PHP website.

Comment: Normalise your data structure and store your comma-delimited lists as related records in another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short and simple: **yes**, change that (this is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

a million rows in a table just containing 3 colums isn't a big deal. you could choose to add two tables instead of just one:

```
minimum_order (restaurant_id, minimum_order_id, amount)

delivery_area (restaurant_id, area_id, minimum_order_id)
```

this will give you the advantage that is the amount for a group of areas changes, just the amount at `minimum_order` needs to be updated instead of multiple rows (one per area) at `minimum_order`.

Comment: great ... one step beyond and much better for managing and updating data ..!! Thanks oezi !

Comment: you're welcome. if this solved your problem, please consider accepting it (and, maybe, voting it up) by clicking the tick-mark to the left of it.

Comment: earlier i had not enough points to vote up an answer...now i have !!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a good move. De-normalizing the database to reduce number of rows is not advisable. There will be several dis-advantages of doing that. It seems like currently you are storing Area Id comma seperated. In that case, you are not able to use index when search by area id. Or probably you have used "Full Text Index" for delivery_area_1, delivery_area_2, delivery_area_3 fields.

If the number of rows are increasing then you can try partitioning techniques.

Please refer http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html